# How to get Executable javafx jar bundled with dependent jars?

Tags: java, ant, javafx-2, packaging, executable-jar

I have made one javafx application form which I get an executable jar as output.
Now my javafx application is dependent on two 3rd party jars like commons.io.2.4.jar.

Presently to run my application, I have to keep these dependent jars in classpath of my executable jar like this

```
--------Application.jar
----------[Classpath Folder]\dependend.jar files
```

**But I want all dependent jars to get bundled in my executable jar itself.**

Since javafx uses ant build I tried using

```
 <jar destfile="application.jar">
        <zipfileset src="Dependent.jar" />
 </jar>
```

but after bundling all dependent jars I am not getting executable jar. I don't know where the problem lies.

I also tried `<fx:jar> </fx:jar>` tags for the same, but not able to figure out how to exactly achieve my requirement.

This is how manifest file somewhat looks like:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
implementation-vendor: dhruv1767
JavaFX-Version: 2.2
implementation-title: LogsDeObfuscator
implementation-version: 1.0
JavaFX-Application-Class: com.liaison.controller.LogsDeObfuscator
JavaFX-Class-Path: lib/allatori.jar lib/commons-io-2.4.jar
Created-By: JavaFX Packager
Main-Class: com/javafx/main/Main

Name: com/javafx/main/Main.class
SHA-256-Digest: j0IuLabX3l0TgeO1+UqESD6fWA09lNsuiTtr4eue1HU=

Name: com/liaison/controller/LogsDeObfuscator.class
SHA-256-Digest: AysvgvCJeJoRdCpqu1xC8JDKttGWUQR4ce8jVW/kLDY=

Name: com/liaison/controller/Delta.class
SHA-256-Digest: TkQcfU1YWr6UwkiIj2IJpFi4UirQK7pDL26pVnAjVYM=
```

Comment: Are the classes of Dependent.jar present in the application.jar? What does the Manifest file of application.jar look like?

Comment: @Puce No classes of dependent jar are not present in application jar... actually thats what I want to attain

Comment: @Puce added manifest file in the question

Comment: I just tried to find some documentation about "JavaFX-Class-Path" but couldn't find any...

Comment: <zipfileset> is not supported in ant javafx task as you used. i am getting ant exception that says zipfile set is not supported in <jar> task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to watch out for is if any of the dependent JARs themselves contain a manifest.

```
<jar destfile="application.jar">
    <zipfileset src="Dependent.jar" excludes="META-INF/MANIFEST.MF/>
</jar>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have face the same problem before i use exe4j for this i have added all the jars that are required and exe4j bundeled all them in one. This works for me. Make sure while adding the jar you add your Main classpath of main Jar.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

http://www.zenjava.com/2012/11/24/from-zero-to-javafx-in-5-minutes/

Maven is required, but will make adding your Commons IO dependency a snap.

Following the directions, I was able to make an executable JAR and native installer for Ubuntu.  Executable JAR generation is done with this command:

```
mvn jfx:build-jar
```

Get the example project from the link working.  Then add the dependency to the POM file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Then you can move your existing code to the Maven managed JavaFX project.

More details are on the link, but to generate a native installer run this command:

```
mvn jfx:build-native
```